SwiftUI statusBarHidden() ignored when virtual keyboard is active on previous view in a NavigationStack
Please look at the code below. There is a NavigationLink on ContentView, which when clicked, navigates to ChildView, where statusBar is supposed to be hidden. Bring up the virtual keyboard by clicking the search field and then click "Hello", you will then see that the status bar on ChildView will be visible. This happens only when the keyboard was shown before the navigation.
I believe it is a bug of iOS or SwiftUI. Does anyone know of a fix?
This is really a big problem for me, because in my case, the ChildView is a game view which is supposed to be full screen.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Hello") {
                    ChildView()
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.green
            .statusBarHidden()
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}

